# Correct way to get the screen size on iOS, after UIScreen.main deprecation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I always used `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` to get the screen size on iOS and worked fine.

Now (in iOS 16, I believe) when I try to access the screen size with the "main" instance of UIScreen a warning is displayed:

*"main' will be deprecated in a future version of iOS: Use a UIScreen instance
found through context instead: i.e, view.window.windowScene.screen*

So my question is:
What is the correct way to get the screen size? for simplicity let's imagine we are on the iPhone with, consequently, only one screen available. Thank you

Comment: This article might be helpful: https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-detect-screen-size

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```swift
extension UIWindow {
    static var current: UIWindow? {
        for scene in UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes {
            guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { continue }
            for window in windowScene.windows {
                if window.isKeyWindow { return window }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


extension UIScreen {
    static var current: UIScreen? {
        UIWindow.current?.screen
    }
}
```

This way, you can use this anywhere, just like you could with the `UIScreen.main`.

## usage

```swift
UIScreen.current?.bounds.size
```

Comment: Best answer out of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Per Apple discussion on `UIScreen.main` deprecation:

> Apple discourages the use of this symbol. Use a UIScreen instance
> found through context instead. For example, reference the screen that
> displays a view through the screen property on the window scene
> managing the window containing the view.

Here is an extension to find the UIScreen instance through context:

```
extension UIViewController {
  func screen() -> UIScreen? {
    var parent = self.parent
    var lastParent = parent
    
    while parent != nil {
      lastParent = parent
      parent = parent!.parent
    }
    
    return lastParent?.view.window?.windowScene?.screen
  }
}
```

For reference, this is the same `UIScreen` instance associated with the `windowScene` in the SceneDelegate:

```
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    let screen = windowScene.screen
    
    configureNavigationBar()
  }
```

Comment: it is a bad approach because sometimes you need to get screen size inside `UIView`

Answer (score 1):

From a ViewController:

```swift
let screenSize = self.view.window?.windowScene?.screen.bounds.size
```

Comment: So this is a solution only if you still use the old ViewController lifecycle? Thanks!

Comment: what if window == nil?