# UIScreen.main is deprecating. What should I replace it with?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, height, width, uiscreen

I'm using swiftUI and I want the width and height of the screen.

It says .main will be depreciated. What should I replace it with? What's the new approach?

I have this code in my project

```
import SwiftUI

let width  = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

I declared this in a global file.
I'm using iOS 16.2 (the latest xcode & iOS)

Comment: Are you use iOS 16?

Comment: YES! The latest and greatest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74458971/correct-way-to-get-the-screen-size-on-ios-after-uiscreen-main-deprecation

Comment: You can always use `GeometryReader`

Comment: Actually, I wanted a different approach. One that keeps these 2 properties. The geometry reader is expensive.