# How do I get `UIScreen.main.scale` after iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

`UIScreen.main.scale` will deprecated.
here it the document in UIKit.UIScreen

```
    @available(iOS, introduced: 2.0, deprecated: 100000, message: "Use a UIScreen instance found through context instead: i.e, view.window.windowScene.screen")
    open class var main: UIScreen { get } // the device's internal screen
```

`deprecated: 100000` means to be deprecated.

So my question is how do I replace this method?

use below method can work in main App, but `UIApplication.shared` doesn't available in extension app. Is there any solution to resolve this problem

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension, unavailable)
extension UIWindow {
    static var current: UIWindow? {
        for scene in UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes {
            guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { continue }
            for window in windowScene.windows {
                if window.isKeyWindow { return window }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

@available(iOSApplicationExtension, unavailable)
extension UIScreen {
    static var current: UIScreen? {
        UIWindow.current?.screen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIViewController {
  func screen() -> UIScreen? {
    var parent = self.parent
    var lastParent = parent
    
    while parent != nil {
      lastParent = parent
      parent = parent!.parent
    }
    
    return lastParent?.view.window?.windowScene?.screen
  }
}
```

and use this extension in

```
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let screen = windowScene.screen
```

check this link for reference
[Correct way to get the screen size on iOS, after UIScreen.main deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74458971/correct-way-to-get-the-screen-size-on-ios-after-uiscreen-main-deprecation)

Comment: That's not what I want.in some cases. we don't have UIViewController in extension app

Comment: what do you mean by extension app??

Comment: extension app is not only widget extension. like `TVTopShelfContentProvider`, `NotificationService extension`, they don't have UIViewController